# Running exe with framework error

Tags: vb.net, compilation, dialog, exe

I have compiled my code in **Visual Basic 2010 Express** to an **.exe** file and It runs perfectly on my Machine (Windows 7 Home Premium 64 Bit).

I want to run this file on an external machine (Windows 7 Home Premium 64 Bit) and I installed the newest version of **Framework** (4.5).

When I start the file, I don't get an error. All I see is the Splash screen of my Application and suddenly the windows7 dialog appears "**This application has stoped working**"

I just can't figure out the problem...

Comment: You can try to search Application event log for errors, can you find anything?

Comment: The simplest answer (not necessarily the correct one, just the simplest) is that your program is throwing an exception which isn't being caught. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/710021/handle-net-exceptions-at-application-level for a way to catch the exception so you can show a message box or something to find out what's going on.